# How to custom validation unique multiple column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, rules

I have the contracts table with (id, name, company)
And my rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'    => 'required',
        'company' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

When I create

Contract one with id = 1, name = A, company = C

Contract two with id = 2, name = A, company = C. It's wrong.

Because I want a company cannot have the same contract name.

If contract two with id = 2, name = B, company = C. It's Okay.

So I want know how custom name and company fields to those two columns bind each other

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom rule closure for this.

```
public function rules()
{
        return [
            'name' => [
                          'required', 
                           function($attribute, $value, $fail) use($this){
                               $exists = \DB::('contracts')->where('company', $this->company)->where('name', $this->name)->exists();
                               if(!exists){
                                   $fail($attribute.'already added for this company.');
                               }
                           }
                      ],
            'company' => 'required'
        ];
}
```

I hope you understand.

You can see documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 1):

The following will work on the create

```php
'name' => 'required|unique:contracts,name,'.$this->id.',NULL,id,company,'.$request->input('company')
```

The (undocumented) format for the unique rule is:

> table[,column[,ignore value[,ignore column[,where column,where
>   value]...]]]

Multiple "where" conditions can be specified, but only equality can be checked. A closure (as in the accepted answer) is needed for any other comparisons.